# Numeric precision specifier out of range while creating a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL code to create a table.

```
-- Table: Yelp_User
-- ADDED TO JAVA FILE
CREATE TABLE Yelp_User (
    Yelp_Id char(22)  NOT NULL,
    Yelping_since date NOT NULL,
    Name varchar2(50)  NOT NULL,
    Average_Stars number(51,50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Yelp_User_pk PRIMARY KEY (Yelp_Id)
) ;
```

However, I get the following error, which I suspect is coming from the average_stars attribute.

```
ORA-01727: numeric precision specifier is out of range (1 to 38)
```

Examples of average_stars values are as follows (from a JSON file I will be parsing):

```
3.8300000000000001
3.9700000000000002
4.4000000000000004
3.7799999999999998
```

Comment: `number(51,50)` has **51** digits in total with **50** digits after decimal point. Do you really want such an unusual (and invalid) type? Note that `3.8300000000000001` value corresponds to `number(17, 16)`

Comment: In Oracle, number precision is limited to 38 - you are setting it to 51, which is invalid. (38 may seem arbitrary, but - almost surely - Oracle bases that on binary numbers with 128 digits; `power(2, 128)` is approximately `power(10, 38)`. None of your numerical values seem to require more than 38 digits of precision.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems really, really clear.

Comment: The error message is exceeding clear. **Oracle only supports numbers to 38 decimal places**. Indeed why would you even need something that precise for a five star rating system? Anyway, if you still don't understand the issue [please look at this demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61283dfa565268f870bd18161356f992)